# What is the fastest way to toggle third-party cookies on/off in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, privacy, user-interface, cookies

In Firefox, what is the fastest way to toggle allowing all third-party cookies vs allowing none of them?

Currently, in Firefox v65.0.2, you have to follow all these steps to enable all third-party cookies:

1. Open Firefox Options
2. Go to the Privacy and Security tab in Options
3. Uncheck 'Cookies'

Then, to toggle it back to blocking all of them, you have to follow all these steps:

1. Open Firefox Options
2. Go to the Privacy and Security tab in Options
3. Check 'Cookies'
4. Click the drop-down next to 'Cookies'
5. Select 'All cookies' from the dropdown

Is there a faster or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Write an AHK macro?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks David.  I was thinking about that.  But I don't think it's possible to write a true AHK macro toggle, because it won't know the state of the Cookies checkbox (unless AHK has advanced to that level).  I could write 2 macros, and assign them to 2 different key combinations, but I would prefer something a little more elegant.

Comment: This [Firefox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/togglecookies/) maybe?

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thanks so much.  That extension toggles *all* cookies, so it won't work, but it's exactly the right idea.

Comment: Not a problem =). Sorry it wasn't more useful.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Type `about:config?filter=network.cookie.cookieBehavior` in your address bar, press TAB, press ENTER and set the value you desire.

- 0 = Accept all cookies by default
- 1 = Only accept from the originating site (block third-party cookies)
- 2 = Block all cookies by
  default

**Source:**

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.cookie.cookieBehavior#Possible_values_and_their_effects

https://www.privacytools.io/#about_config

**Two cents:**

You may write an extension to modify these values with the click of a button if you know javascript and absolutely need the quickest way to do the above task.
Personally, I would just bookmark the above link and modify the values as required.

Comment: Just FYI, Mozilla recently removed the ability to directly access about:config entries via a URL. :(